# Javascript Error,Escaping Problem,Grid not working,Error on Firebug

Tags: javascript, grid, sigma-grid-control

we are just started with Sigma Grid ,and it is awesome in its functionality when we compared to other Grids.

But i encountered some problem with Sigma Grid ,or may be with javascript.
I dont know whether  the problem is with Grid or with my code.

**I have a table with 3 fields namely MailID,MailName,MailData.**

MailID is int ,MailName and MailData contains HTML content and it save as string in database.

When i load the Grid,i have some problems.

**Problem 1 :**

---

As i said above the Maildata contain html content,the following image is just a example with <*b>  ,u can see that the HTML is automatically rendering on the grid itself ,i need the exact string.

please check the following image.

**Problem 2 :**

---

as u can see i have links on the grid,for edit,send,delete but on one filed its damaged.[check the image below ]

the code i used to render links is following .

```
{id: 'mailid' ,  header: "Action", width :120 , resizable : false, sortable : false , printable : false ,
        renderer : function(value ,record,columnObj,grid,colNo,rowNo){
                var no= record[columnObj.fieldIndex];
                var cod =  (record['maildata']);
                return '<a href=\"#\" class=\"myli\" onClick="showalert('+no+');">Edit</a> | <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"alert('+cod+')\";>Send</a> | <a href=\"#\">Delete</a>';
```

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/f02c01.png]

**Problem 3 :**

---

The third value of MailData is 5 and it is integer ,when i alert the value its shows it correctly.
check the following image.
[image: http://i51.tinypic.com/2uqivyv.png]

But when i alert the second value of maildata it giving error ,the second value of MailData is "hai newuser" ,it showing the following error on firebug.

```
missing ) after argument list
 alert(hai newuser)
```

check the image below.

[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/2dc7h8k.png]

But when i alert 9th value of MailData it run correctly ,the content is <*b>poy<*/b> ,this one is also save as string,but the grid automatically BOLD [which i dnt like].Check the image below.
[image: http://i53.tinypic.com/10fceb4.png]

also there are some others the 7the value contain ;".: etc ,also  /b ,when i alert the data it showing the following error,

```
unexpected end of XML source
 alert(<b>jjfdslkdjflsdnfsldfnf
```

dsOptions and ColOptions are following .

```
var dsOption= {

    fields :[
        {name : 'mailid'  },
        {name : 'mailname',type:"text"  },
        {name : 'maildata',type:"text"  }






    ],

    recordType : 'object',


}


    function my_renderer(value ,record,columnObj,grid,colNo,rowNo)
    {
        var no= record[columnObj.fieldIndex];
        return "<img src=\"./images/flag_" + no.toLowerCase() + ".gif\">";
        }
        function showalert(no)
        {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {



        $.post("http://localhost/power/index.php/power/give",{ name: no}, function(data)
            {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            $("#editor").show("fast");
            $( '#txtar' ).ckeditor();
            $('#txtar' ).val( data.maildata );
            //$("#editor").html(data);
            },"json"
         );

        });
        }



var colsOption = [
     {id: 'mailid' , header: "Mail ID" , width :60},
     {id: 'mailname' , header: "Mail Name" , width :160 ,type:"text"},
       {id: 'maildata' , header: "Mail Data" , width :190,type:"text" },
        {header: "Group" , width :70,
     editor : { type :"select" ,options : {'php':'php','asp':'asp'} 
     ,defaultText : 'php' }  },


       {id: 'mailid' ,  header: "Action", width :120 , resizable : false, sortable : false , printable : false ,
        renderer : function(value ,record,columnObj,grid,colNo,rowNo){
                var no= record[columnObj.fieldIndex];
                var cod =  (record['maildata']);
                return '<a href=\"#\" class=\"myli\" onClick="showalert('+no+');">Edit</a> | <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"alert('+cod+')\";>Send</a> | <a href=\"#\">Delete</a>';
            }  } 
];
```

I am littlebit new in Javascript and Sigmagrid,i think that i am doing something worst with codes,pls help me to success.

Thank you.

*Note : i posted the same Question on Sigma Grid Forum too,i think that it is not a problem.*

Comment: I am sorry,this post may b beautiful if sof allow to post images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 2

The string `cod` contains a `>`

Problem 3

The string `hai newuser` needs to be contained in `"` or `'` or it is considered a variable name

Basically you have to decide -- are you going to validate the html or not.  If you don't validate the HTML then html errors in the data will show as errors on your page.  You could also HTML escape the html so you will see the HTML codes -- this is probably the best plan.

Other sites use (like this one) use markdown -- this is easier to validate -- then they generate the actual HTML before display.

In addition you are having problems with the alert.  Alert displays strings not HTML so you will see what you are seeing -- different results than expected depending on the HTML.

---

I would take a step back and ask yourself -- what is the type of the data, how am I going to display it.  How am I going to validate that if it is HTML it is valid.

There are the problems you need to address -- your examples all stem from this problem.

Comment: the string hai user is a string ,and it is assigned to a variable,then how can i use " or ' ?? also MailData is HTML so i need to escape to show that ? but i need to see the actual content without any modification.

Comment: i am saving the data as a string ,also the content may or maynot contain HTML,its depended.and COD is string,so i think that i can alert that normally ,but its not working here.

Comment: `var cod =  record['maildata'];
    return '<a href=\"#\" class=\"myli\" onClick="samep('+cod+');">Edit</a> | <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"alert('+cod+')\";>Send</a> | <a href=\"#\">Delete</a>';` this is the exact code behind this the variable COD returns string,then why i cant show the alert ?